# how to add friendly name for hyperlinks in microsoft access based on a field?

Tags: hyperlink

In my Microsoft Access ( 2013 ) Project, I have two fields. One for the company name ( text type ) and another for the company websites ( hyperlink data type ). is there a way I can create a new field with a friendly name based on the company name field? (there are tons of records in my database, so I can't do this manually by editing one by one).
in Excel, I do this by HYPERLINK(friendly name, link location) formula. but how can I do this in Access 2013?

Answer (score 0):

in Access, or really any SQL db, one would add a new field to the table.

then create a query that has a calculated field which strings together / concatenates the data as you wish it to be.

then run that query as an update query on the table to fill in the values in the new field.